# Difference between identical and equal?

Tags: objective-c

I am having trouble understanding the concept between two things being equal and two things being identical. What confuses me is the statement "Two objects can be identical, which means they are equal. But, two object that are equal are not identical." Could someone please help me understand the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in objective-c, slightly pseudo code...

```
NSString * a = @"hello";
NSString * b = @"hello";

a == a    //they are identical (the same object)
[a isEqualToString:a]; //they are equal.
a != b    //Even though the string contents are the same they are not the same object.
[a isEqualToString:b]; // they aren't identical but they are equal.
```

For a very long and good blog post on the topic see this

http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2008/01/07/equality-vs-identity/

Comment: I should know this, but I am blanking. Aren't == and "isEqual" the same thing?

Comment: Not in objective-c. Variables are pointers to objects in memory. `==` compares pointers. `isEqualToString:` compares the actual characters of the strings.

Comment: Ok. So == is like saying "See if these two people live on the same street" (street being the address in memory and people being the objects). And isEqualToString is asking if those two people have the same name?

Comment: Yes thats the concept. :) and if the two people happen to live at the same address then they must be _exactly_ the same person.

Comment: Actually, in Objective-C, I think Dave is right for the case of NSStrings and a few other types, but not all NSObjects. See my answer my below for clarification.

Comment: @jackslash from Apple docs: "The default NSObject implementation of `isEqual:` simply checks for pointer equality." This should be the same as ==, which is what was saying. Your example compares == to `isEqualToString:` which is a different method altogether. [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html)

Comment: @nvrtedfrst Thats not the point. The point is to demonstrate the difference between objects being equal and identical. Also if you call `isEqual:` on an `NSString` you'll find it eventually does `isEqualToString:` if both objects are `NSString`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of boxes... (this works a lot better with pictures, apologies I haven't included any)

**Preamble**

When you write:

```
int x;
```

you are asking for a *box* which is capable of holding an *int* and to equate the name of that with *x* - all boxes have an internal name, what it exactly is is unimportant. So now when you write:

```
x = 4;
```

you asking to store the *value* 4 in the *box* referenced by the name *x*. A box is often called a "variable". This use of boxes is why computer programming is different from mathematics, you can write:

```
x = x + 1;
```

in computer programming, but not in maths! It means "go to the box referenced by *x*, copy the value out, add 1 it to, put the value back into the same box".

Now boxes of different types (meaning what can be stored in them) can be "glued" together to form multi-compartment boxes. The whole collection is referred to by a single name, and the individual boxes by two names - the one for the collection and the one for the individual box. Such collections of boxes appear in different programming languages under the terms "record", "structure", "object" etc.

And finally, what can you put in a box? The answer (depending on the rules of the programming language) is *anything* and this includes the *names of other boxes*. E.g. you can write:

```
int *y;
```

which asks for a box capable of holding the "name of a box which holds an integer" and to call this box *y*. Such boxes are often called "pointer variables" or "reference variables"

**`==` vs. `isEqual`**

In Objective-C the `==` operator looks at the contents of two boxes and determines whether they contain the same *value* - and that *value* might well be the name of another box.

The `isEqual` method operates only on boxes (of certain restricted types) which contain the names of other boxes. It looks into the two boxes, uses the names in those boxes to locate two more boxes, and then compares the contents of those boxes. If the boxes it is comparing themselves contain other boxes which contain names of yet further boxes then it traverses to those further boxes to compare them, etc.

Furthermore `isEqual` does not need to compare for exact equality, but is allowed to compare for "means the same thing". E.g. if you create two dictionaries which contain the same key/value pairs but they are entered in different orders then the arrangement of boxes that make up those two dictionaries may not be identical, but semantically they are the same - the `isEqualDictionary:` method is defined as:

> Two dictionaries have equal contents if they each hold the same number of entries and, for a given key, the corresponding value objects in each dictionary satisfy the `isEqual:` test.

**Conclusion**

The `==` operator is usually only used for "primitive" data types - `int`, `float`, `NSInteger` etc. - and structures of such types - e.g. NSRect. These are the types where the *values* determine equality.

The `isEqual:` method is is usually used for Obj-C objects - you usually don't want to know whether to boxes contain the same name (which is what `==` would determine), but whether what those names refer to are semantically equivalent - which is what `isEqual:` determines.

Answer (score 0):

Identical generally means they are the same object in memory (occupy the same memory footprint).
Equal usually means their attribute values are the same.